# HP Envy 5530 and Linux Ubunu 14.04

Tags: usb, printing

I can't install HP ENVY 5530 using USB Cable  in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: I Can´t see my HP ENVY 5532 in system settings -> Printer while using cable... WIFI printing is OK. Printing in WIndows i OK.

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole collection of printer handling/configuration tools provided by HP, installed with `apt-get install hplip-gui`.

The command to directly open a dialog to add an USB printer is [`hp-setup`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/hp-setup.1.html). It can also be used in text mode with the `-i` option, if you like to use it over ssh or so.

Run
[`hp-check`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/hp-check.1.html) 
and
[`hp-doctor`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/hp-doctor.1.html) 
for automatic diagnostics.
You can access many of the other tools for 
[`hp-toolbox`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/hp-toolbox.1.html) for others.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those HP printers that doesn't seem to have Gutenprint drivers, so download HP's Linux open source drivers [here](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/downloads.html), and follow [this](http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/install/index.html) guide to install the driver utility and get the printer to work. It should have support for the HP Envy 5530.

Answer (score 0):

This link really helped me: https://answers.launchpad.net/hplip/+question/210089

> Latest HPLIP packages uses libusb-1.0 version instead of libusb-0.1
>   version. Where as Officejet G85 is old printer, this doesn't support
>   libusb-1.0.
>
> Please make following changes:
>
> ```
> $ cd ~/Downloads/hplip-3.12.9 #assuming hplip-3.12.9.run file is downloaded in ~/Downloads folder, change accordingly.
>
> $ ./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-libusb01_build
> $ make
> $ sudo make install
>
> $ hp-toolbox
> ```
>
> - Remove print queue using "-" symbols in toolbox
> - Power Off and Power On printer
> - Add print queue using "+" symbols in toolbox